# Prevent duplicate calls with AngularJS method binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to hide a span if the context of the span is empty.  However, the content of the span is some complicated calculation.  What I want to do, is exactly below, however, I do not want to call the function twice.  The element below is also in a "Loop" (ASP.NET MVC foreach in the razor page :( ).

Here is is

```
@for(...) {
<span ng-hide="GetDataCount() > 0">{{GetDataCount()}}</span>
}
```

As you can see, this will work, but I have to call the function 2 times.  Any ideas how I can make this work if the "span" element we're currently in doesn't have a value? (i.e. if GetDataCount returns null or 0).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-init` to set a value:

```
<span ng-init="count = GetDataCount()" ng-hide="count > 0">{{count}}</span>
```

Comment: Please note the warning in the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit): The **only** appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat.

Comment: Wouldn't this case be similar to the ng-init example?  Aliasing "count" as GetDataCount() result?

Comment: @Dave -- It's a bit of a special case since this is residing within a server-side repeater